# sql query rows in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

i would like to display the following table view in lines.

```
          date          | id  | value_1 | value_2 |
------------------------+-----+--------------------
 2006-12-31 05:00:00+01 |   1 |    12   |    8    |
 2006-12-31 05:00:00+01 |   2 |     9   |    4    |
 2006-12-31 04:40:00+01 |   1 |     4   |   14    |
 2006-12-31 04:40:00+01 |   2 |    11   |    1    |
 2006-12-31 04:20:00+01 |   1 |     5   |    4    |
 2006-12-31 04:20:00+01 |   2 |    21   |    3    |
```

The values ​​are to be added. The value of value_1 with ID=1 is to be added to the value of value_2 ID=2. And the value of value_2 with ID=1 is to be added to the value of value_1 ID=2.
I would like to receive the following view. Output should be sorted by date.

```
          date          | Numerator | Denominator |
------------------------+-----------+-------------+
 2006-12-31 05:00:00+01 |    16     |    15       |
 2006-12-31 04:40:00+01 |     5     |    23       |
 2006-12-31 04:20:00+01 |     8     |    25       |
```

I created the following sql query, but the values ​​are not added together

```
SELECT date,
sum(case when id=1 then value_1 end) as Numerator, 
sum(case when id=2 then value_2 end) as Denominator 
from table 
group by date 
Order By date DESC;
```

Comment: There's a kpi_figure_id column in your query. Where does it come from?

Comment: You explain one of the columns, but the last column is still a mystery.

Comment: i changed the column name.

Comment: I added the description for the second column. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: @Zeynep . . . Please explain how `15` is calculated for the first row.  It does not seem related to any of the values in the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I add up the value 8 with the value 9. But I see, i made a mistake in the calculation. It should be 17 not 15.

Answer (score 1):

> The value of value_1 with ID=1 is to be added to the value of value_2 ID=2.

```
SELECT date,
       sum(case when id = 1 then value_1
                when id = 2 then value_2
           end) as new_value
from table 
group by date 
Order By date DESC;
```

I'm not sure why your result set has two value columns when your description only explains one.

Based on your description -- BUT NOT THE DATA -- the second column appears to be:

```
SELECT date,
       sum(case when id = 1 then value_1
                when id = 2 then value_2
           end) as numerator,
       sum(case when id = 1 then value_2
                when id = 2 then value_1
           end) as denominator
from table 
group by date 
Order By date DESC;
```

Comment: the id = 1, value_1 belongs to the numerator and value_2 to the denominator. the id = 2, value_1 takes the denominator and value_2 the numerator. I need the two value columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```
SELECT 
    date_column,
    SUM((CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN value_1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN value_2 ELSE 0 END)) AS Numerator,
    SUM((CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN value_2 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN value_1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Denominator
FROM table
GROUP BY date_column
ORDER BY date_column DESC;
```

Output:

```
|       date            | Numerator | Denominator |
|-----------------------|-----------|-------------|
|2006-12-31 05:00:00+01 |    16     |    17       |
|2006-12-31 04:40:00+01 |     5     |    25       |
|2006-12-31 04:20:00+01 |     8     |    25       |
```

I do not understand how you calculate de Denominator.

Comment: Your denominator calculations are wrong: 8 + 9 = 17 and 14 + 11 = 25.